# how to format a a url to return something like this "product/4/improved-led-lamp" in the template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to return a formatted url that will look like this "edit-book/4/improved-led-lamp" using the {% url %} tag

I've tried `{% url 'dashboard:editbook' 4 slug %}`

here is the root url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

here is my dashboard app's urls,py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'dashboard'
urlpatterns = [
   path('edit-book/<int:id>/<slug:title>', views.BookView.as_view(), name='editbook'),
]
```

if I visit "edit-book/4/improved-led-lamp" in my browser, it resolves, but when I try to reproduce this in the view using {% url %} tag, it throws noReverseMatch error

this is the error
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz7m0.png)

Comment: Please show the full error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I just uploaded a screenshot of the error, plus i've edited the code to provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct and if `slug` variable consists of slug (`[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+`) it should be working.

Look into contents of `slug`. Error screenshot shows that it's an empty string.

Comment: screenshot shows that `slug` variable is empty string. You need an actual slug there.